# Audio not working on Acer Swift 5 with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, acer, 22.04

**Full model**: Acer Swift 5 SF515-51T V.104 
**OS**: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64 
**Kernel**: 5.15.0-27-generic 
**Packages**: 1823 (dpkg), 9 (snap) 
**Shell**: bash 5.1.16

The audio jack does work, probably a speaker issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and same issue. Its a regression on linux kernel. Try any kernel older or same as 5.9.1 and audio and microphones should work out of the box !

Comment: does it work on other distros? I installed Arch on the laptop and it still has the issues on kernel 5.18

Comment: Yes, as long as you are on kernel 5.9.1 or older, audio works on all distros ! For arch linux look at the package archive and download linux-5.9.1 and relevant headers (If you need them) and Add linux package ko pacman's ignore list to prevent it from updating !